# asp.net gridview filterexpression showing wrong result

Tags: asp.net

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HIbuddyConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT ID,owner,PostedBy,Path,PostDate,status,
                    CASE status
                    WHEN '0'  THEN 'New'
                    WHEN '1'  THEN 'Listened'
                    WHEN '99' THEN 'Removed'
                    else ' unknown'
                    END as StatusName
                    FROM Tbl_wallpost
                    WHERE CONVERT (varchar(10), PostDate, 103) &gt;= @dateFrom AND CONVERT (varchar(10), PostDate, 103) &lt;= @dateTo" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE Tbl_wallpost SET status=@status WHERE ID=@ID"
        DataSourceMode="DataSet"

        FilterExpression="owner='{0}'" EnableCaching="true">
                <FilterParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="owner" ControlId="ownerNo" PropertyName="Text"/>

                </FilterParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="dateFrom" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="dateTo" PropertyName="Text" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

My problem is when i want to write FilterExpression="owner='{0}' OR PostedBy='{1}'" the filter is showing wrong result? whats the reason? I need to filter data by owner and posted by individually.PLz suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FilterExpression="owner='{0}' OR PostedBy='{1}'"
```

should work as long as you have two `FilterParameters`

```
<FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="owner" ControlId="ownerNo" 
                   PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"/>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="PostedBy" ControlId="PostedBy" 
                   PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"/>
</FilterParameters>
```

Comment: when i add single expression as FilterExpression="owner='{0}'" then it works perfect but when i add another filter paratmeter then its show wrong resuslt.

Comment: @user try including  `ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"` as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem of create two or more "Like clause" in the "Where" statement using:
`Where CHARINDEX(@Par1, Col1)<>0) and ...`